# Deleting spaces in string and put one in front

Tags: php

High,

I'm using this function

```
function special_chars_replace($string){
    $result = preg_replace("/[&%\$#@'\*:\/\"\[\]\{\};\(\)\|\\\=!\^\?`~.,\+-]/", "", $string);
    return $result;
}
```

to delete all spaces in a css class name.

```
<?php echo special_chars_replace(strtolower(str_replace(" ","",$itemTags))); ?>
```

How do i preserve the first space before the name? So i can use it for a css class name. For example: class="tags tag01 tag02"

Comment: Could you give an example of what `$itemTags` could look like and how the result should then look like?

Comment: example: " Kinder, Haus" gets converted to "kinderhaus". But I need the spacer for a class name with several classes.

Comment: So you want the result to be "Kinder Haus" then?

Comment: the result should be " kinderhaus".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the space before you echo the string:

```
<?php 
echo " ".special_chars_replace(strtolower(str_replace(" ","",$itemTags)));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<?php echo implode(" ",explode(" ",$itemTags)); ?>
```

Comment: How would that change the string at all?

Comment: explode function breaks a string into an array by `explode('your_delimeter_from_you_want_to_slice',$your_string); `                                                                                          and implode converts an array to string placing a seperator( you can mention any of symbol, character or number) `implode('your_seperator',$your_array)`

Comment: And implode undoes that change... so it's the same as before (at least with PHP 7)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression is the most effective way to do this.

```
echo preg_replace(' +', ' ', $itemTags);
```

What this does is look for one or more spaces (that's what the `+` does), and replaces it with a single space.

*Code typed from memory.*